# Edit encoded SVG base64 image in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, decode, encode

It's possible to edit base64 encoded SVG image in react by adding some text fields in it?

I have base64 data that comming form server and displaying in a <img src="data:JPG;base64,..." tag.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzAhf.png)

Problem is that, when I try to decode base64 string by using `window.atob` in consle getting something similiar to ASCII:
[decoded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkShp.png)

any ideas how to get raw SVG data like `<svg> <path d="..."/></svg>` so that I can modify and add `<text>` ags in it and encode again

Comment: That's a png image and not svg at all.

Comment: does it means that `window.atob` actually decoded image just console.log not able to render PNG image?

Comment: is that correct? Not displaying in cosnsole because of PNG ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In the second image in your post you have decoded the base64 string into the binary code of the PNG. In the first image in your post the img tag looks like a base64 string of a jpeg image.

Comment: Maybe you should look the backend code and see if/where your SVG images are converted to PNG. Maybe that can be disabled so that you get the SVG to the frontend.

Comment: It's possible to "somehow" add image text on decoded PNG image?

Will definetly investigate fro ma backend side, thank you very much for your responses